# buttons not resizing proportionally to form

Tags: c#, resize

I am developing a Paint program , and i need to resize all the buttons in my form Relatively to the Resizing event.

**Example :**

Form start-up Size **(800,600)**

Buttons start-up Size **(41,41)**

If i resize the form to **(1000,900)** , the buttons must resize to **(241,341)**.

After that..

If i resize the form to **(900,800)** , the buttons must resize to **(141,241)**.

After that..

If i resize the form to **(400,400)** , the buttons must resize to **(41,41)**.

I tried to write a code to do that , it worked.

But when i **decrease** the size of the form alot , it keeps decreasing and i can see the button almost disappear , instead of staying on the default Size **(41,41)**

Note: in case of decreasing the form with values that pass down the buttons size , the buttons should remain at the default size **(41,41)** !

`Pen` is a button.

My code:

```
    private int previousHeight;
    private int previousWidth;
    private int OriginalRectSize = 41;

     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        previousHeight = this.Size.Height;
        previousWidth = this.Size.Width;
    }


 private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            int newWidth = this.Width - previousWidth; // difference value to add/decrease
            int newHeight = this.Height - previousHeight; // difference value to add/decrease

            //decrease case
            if (newWidth < 0 && newHeight < 0)
            {
                //below button's default size case
                if ((Pen.Width + newWidth) < OriginalRectSize || (Pen.Height + newHeight) < OriginalRectSize)
                {
                    Pen.Width = OriginalRectSize;
                    Pen.Height = OriginalRectSize;
                }
                //decrease 
                else
                {
                    Pen.Width = Pen.Width + newWidth;
                    Pen.Height = Pen.Height + newHeight;
                }
            }

            // increase case
            else
            {
                Pen.Width = Pen.Width + newWidth;
                Pen.Height = Pen.Height + newHeight;
            }


        //set new form size
            previousHeight = this.Height;
            previousWidth = this.Width;

    }
```

Comment: look at the four anchors you can set! they'll do what you want even if that is by no means proportional! no need for the resize unless you want to code more than 2 controls in a row or column. also look at th form's minimum sizes to prevent stupic shrinking!

Comment: but i already started writing code , and i don't know how to use the anchors , and i would like to do it with code.

Comment: the anchor property is set in the properties tab. you need to learn about it in any case, why not now?! it'll be not enough for all cases. a complex layout will combine them, splitpanels and a few more tricks as well as code in the resize event.

Comment: BTW: a Pen is a Pen, don't call anything Pen unless it __is__ a Pen!

Comment: @TaW But it's a button , that's my button's name.

Comment: Pen is a class you'll need in your program. Rename it so you don't confuse everybody, including, in a few days, yourself! BTW: Why would you want a button to change its size?? the canvas should grow, not any of the tools imo!

Comment: @TaW I know , right ? That's exactly what i asked myself , it's not me, it's a final project to a subject i study.

Comment: There is no point in writing code for this.  In the designer, simply modify Anchor and add bottom and right.  And set the MinimumSize property to (41, 41).